# Define MYSQL index with condition

Tags: mysql, index, index-tuning

I have a table with these schemas:

```
 CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `is_deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `transaction_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `ref_transaction_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `action` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `balance` decimal(16,2) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_transaction_id` (`transaction_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

When `action = 1`, `ref_transaction_id` will be `0` 
When `action > 1` (other values are `2,3,4,5`), `ref_transaction_id` will be a non-zero integer. It actually the `transaction_id` of a previous record in the same table.

I want to create index to support for this query:

```
select * 
from transactions 
where `created`>="?" and `created`<= "?" and `ref_transaction_id`=0 and `action`=1
```

I feel like a composite index like **(`action, ref_transaction_id, created`)** will not so efficient since my usage only check for `ref_transaction_id = 0` ( which is roughly 20% of data). Any better way to define composite index with condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like:

- if action=1, then ref_transaction_id can only be 0, **and**
- if ref_transaction_id=0, the action can only be 1

If that's correct, then the query may be simplified:

```
select * 
from transactions 
where `created` between "?" and "?" and `action`=1;
```

Notes:

- add an index for `action` to help the query
- use `between` to range check the date; suspect minor performance improvement

---

#### Unsolicited Observations

This sounds like a linked list (`ref_transaction_id`s) and a state machine (`action`). If that's true, or close, may want to consider putting that info into a separate "association" table,

```
....
`fk_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`transaction_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`fk_prior_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT "replaces use of ref_transaction_id",
`action` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
....
```

Notes:

- introduces `fk_prior_id` as a way of finding the `ref_transaction_id` using a field which is already indexed, `id`
- consider adding the date fields depending on the 
  nature of the data
- consider defining `action` as an enum to capture the state and improve readability; still stored as an integer internally but may be referenced using the defined "states" in queries.

Answer (score 1):

For

```
where `created`>= "?"
  and `created`<= "?"
  and `ref_transaction_id`=0
  and `action`=1
```

The optimal index is

```
INDEX(ref_transaction_id, action,  -- in either order
      created)
```

All the relevant rows with be adjacent in the index.

It does not matter what values `ref_transaction_id` and `action`; it does not matter that they are correlated; it does not matter what the 'cardinality' of each is.  What matters is that you are testing both of them with `=`

If you remove `ref_transaction_id` from the `WHERE` clause, then you need to remove it from the index (or have another index).  Else, the Optimizer will assume that there could be multiple different values for that column and not use all of the index columns.

May I suggest this coding pattern:

```
where `created` >= ?
  and `created`  < ? + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

if, for example, the range is one week.  Also, both `?` will take on the same date, no need for *you* to play with leap year, end of year, 31 days in some months, etc.

Are there multiple rows for a single `transaction_id`?  If not, why not make it the `PRIMARY KEY` and get rid of `id`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. In the end, I choose (action, created) as composite index.